# Dexterity Custom Year Range on Date Field

Tags: plone, dexterity

I'm building content type using dexterity. We've date of birth field and by default year range is +- 10 year from current year.

Date field need to be modify and year should start from 1950. I did bit goggling and couldn't find right information I'm after.

Below is my DOB field definition.

```
dob = schema.Date(
    title=_(u"Date of Birth"),
    )
```

Any advise or reference would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `collective.z3cform.datetimewidget` (https://github.com/collective/collective.z3cform.datetimewidget)
for your field.

This widget has a `yearRange` attribute.
By default it gets the range defined in `site_properties`: `calendar_starting_year` and `calendar_future_years_available`

Check the [documentation](http://docs.plone.org/develop/addons/schema-driven-forms/customising-form-behaviour/widgets.html) if you don't know how to setup the widget

BTW since Version [1.2.4](https://github.com/collective/collective.z3cform.datetimewidget/pull/5/files), You can set the min/max value on the field.

Comment: Hi Mat, do you mind provide example with year range or link for it. I'm bit new with dexterity and widget is almost alien to me.

Comment: @webbyfox Hey, I just saw it's much easier now. Since version 1.2.4 it's support a min and max value --> https://github.com/collective/collective.z3cform.datetimewidget/pull/5/files. I updated the Answer